# How to Handle Connection Pool Request with ASP .Net and MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have created web service using  ASP .Net and MySQL for Android App. When I am calling  my web service through android app or any browser in every 30 seconds then every thing is fine. But I want to call my web service in every 5 seconds then I am getting below error. How can i fix this ?

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"error connecting: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.","ExceptionType":"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Http.ApiController.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()"}

Below is Fucntion from my  webservice. I have used Disposed also after connection close.

```
public Object get_running_status(string shiftid, string stopid, string routeid)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = Connect.getconnection();
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            //MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();

            //MySqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
            try
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //sqlCmd.CommandText = "select btrack.bt_stop.curr_route_id as route_id,start_loc as start_location,end_loc as end_location,loc_name as waypoints_name,lat_val as waypoints_latitude,long_val as waypoints_longitude from btrack.bt_route join btrack.bt_stop on btrack.bt_route.route_id=btrack.bt_stop.curr_route_id where btrack.bt_stop.curr_route_id=(select curr_route_id from btrack.bt_stop where stop_id=" + stopid + " and shift_cd='" + shiftid + "' limit 1) and btrack.bt_stop.lat_val<>0;SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @customer_no = btrack.bt_stop.stop_id THEN @row_number + 1        ELSE 1    END  as rn,btrack.bt_stop.loc_name,btrack.bt_stop.stop_id, ifnull(bus_id,0) bus_id, ifnull  (device_id,0) device_id, ifnull(route_id,0) route_id,ifnull( cast(actual_time as time),0) actual_time, ifnull(actual_lat,0)actual_lat, ifnull( actual_long,0)actual_long, ifnull(current_eta,0) current_eta,ifnull(  run_status,'NA')run_status, ifnull(created_on,0) as created_on, btrack.bt_stop.Shift_cd   FROM btrack.bt_running right  join btrack.bt_stop on btrack.bt_running.shift_cd=btrack.bt_stop.shift_cd  and btrack.bt_running.stop_id=btrack.bt_stop.stop_id  where  btrack.bt_stop.shift_cd='1' order by btrack.bt_stop.stop_id";
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "bt_fill_view3";
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_shift", shiftid);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_loc_id", stopid);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_route_id", routeid);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //sqlCmd1.CommandText = "select sl_no,loc_name,eta,actual_time,run_status,color_flag from bt_view_stop where shift_cd = '"+ shiftid + "' and bus_id = (select curr_bus_id from bt_stop where stop_id = '" + stopid + "') order by sl_no";

                sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
                //sqlCmd1.Connection = conn;
                da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                //sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //da1.SelectCommand = sqlCmd1;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dt.Rows.Count; i1++)
                {
                    Running_Status running_status_model = new Running_Status();
                    running_status_model.ResponseCode = "102";
                    running_status_model.Status = "Success";
                    running_status_model.rn = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i1]["sl_no"]);
                    running_status_model.location = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i1]["stop_name"]);
                    running_status_model.stop_id = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i1]["scheduled_time"]);
                    //running_status_model.bus_id = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i1]["estimated_time"]);
                    running_status_model.device_id = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i1]["running_status"]);
                    running_status_model.route_id = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i1]["color_flag"]);

                    running_statuslist.Add(running_status_model);

                }



                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                return running_statuslist;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Running_Status running_status_model = new Running_Status();
                running_status_model.ResponseCode = "101";
                running_status_model.Status = "Error : " + ex;
                running_statuslist.Add(running_status_model);
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                return running_statuslist;
            }



        }
```

Comment: Seems like you are not closing the connection to the database which causes the pool to be depleted

Comment: Maybe you should post a code snippet of a typical database operation you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please check my update question above.

Comment: put `conn.Close();` and `conn.Dispose();` in `finally` block and see if it helps

Comment: How exactly is `running_statuslist` initialised? Is the function hitting exceptions?